# Как сделать чтобы цикл выводил сообщения в котором я ввел данные. После добавления двух товаров, цикл вводит 10 сообщений, и данные идут в разброс?

Tags: python, for, aiogram

Есть панель администратора

```
    from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command

from data import config, items
from keyboards.default.admin_panel_keyboards import admin_panel_keyboard, admin_panel_keyboard_category, \
    admin_panel_confirm_keyboard
from loader import dp
from states.admin_panel_state import AdminAppend


# Показывает категории администратору
@dp.message_handler(Command('Admin'), user_id=config.admins)
async def admin_panel_category(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Панель администратора\n'
                         'Выберите категорию где нужно сделать измениния', reply_markup=admin_panel_keyboard_category)


# Инстаграмм
@dp.message_handler(text='Instagram', user_id=config.admins)
async def admin_panel_instagram(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Что нужно?', reply_markup=admin_panel_keyboard)


# Добавления товара в инстаграме
@dp.message_handler(text='Добавить товар', user_id=config.admins)
async def admin_panel_instagram_append(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Введите названия товара')
    await AdminAppend.one.set()


@dp.message_handler(user_id=config.admins, state=AdminAppend.one)
async def title_append(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    title_edit = message.text
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['title1'] = title_edit
    await message.answer('Введите описания товара')
    await AdminAppend.next()


@dp.message_handler(user_id=config.admins, state=AdminAppend.two)
async def description_append(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    description_edit = message.text
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['description1'] = description_edit
    await message.answer('Введите цену товара')
    await AdminAppend.next()


@dp.message_handler(user_id=config.admins, state=AdminAppend.three)
async def price_append(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    price_edit = message.text
    price_edit = str(price_edit)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['price1'] = price_edit
    await message.answer('Введите id товара\n'
                         '<i>Начинайте от первого</i>')
    await AdminAppend.next()


@dp.message_handler(user_id=config.admins, state=AdminAppend.four)
async def id_append(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Отправьте ссылку на товар')
    id_edit = message.text
    id_edit = str(id_edit)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['id1'] = id_edit
    await AdminAppend.next()


@dp.message_handler(user_id=config.admins, state=AdminAppend.five)
async def items_link(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    link = message.text
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['link1'] = link
    await message.answer('Подтвердить создания нового товара?', reply_markup=admin_panel_confirm_keyboard)
    await AdminAppend.next()


@dp.message_handler(user_id=config.admins, text='Подтвердить', state=AdminAppend.six)
async def confirm(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Товар создан - /shop')
    data = await state.get_data()
    title = data.get('title1')
    description = data.get('description1')
    price = data.get('price1')
    id_id = data.get('id1')
    link = data.get('link')
    items.title_instagram.append(title)
    items.description_instagram.append(description)
    items.price_instagram.append(price)
    items.id_instagram.append(id_id)
    items.link_instagram.append(link)
    await state.finish()
```

Есть списки в которые попадают данные веденные админом для создания товара

```
title_instagram = []
description_instagram = []
price_instagram = []
id_instagram = []
link_instagram = []

items_instagram = [title_instagram, description_instagram, price_instagram, id_instagram]
```

Есть скрипт который выводит пользователю созданный админом товар

```
    @dp.message_handler(Command('shop'))
async def show_shop(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('<b>Страница магазина</b>', reply_markup=shop_keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='back')
async def show_shop_but_inline(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.edit_reply_markup()
    await call.message.answer('<b>Страница магазина</b>', reply_markup=shop_keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='Instagram')
async def instagram(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.edit_reply_markup()
    await call.answer(cache_time=60)
    caption = """
    {title}
    <pre>{description}</pre>
    {price}
    """
    for items in items_instagram:
        for title in items:
            for description in items:
                for price in items:
                    for id_id in items:
                        await call.message.answer(caption.format(title=title, description=description,
                                                                 price=price), reply_markup=keyboard(item_id=id_id))
```

Админ добавил один товар, отлично! Все работает, бот выводит одно сообщения, в котором все правильно указано!
Админ добавил второй товар, бот выводит 9-10 сообщений в котором еще и разбросаны данные
[image: Администратор добавил только один товар]

[image: Администратор добавил 2 товара]